# Can't Set a Converted Date from String as Minimum Date in DatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have two datepickers that contains time with format 7:00 AM and 8:00 PM for login and logout. These times may vary. I wanted to change the logout time and tried to use the login time as the minimum time but my code does not work, I can still select time like 1:00 AM or 6:00 AM as logout.

This is the code in my ViewDidLoad

```
if let actualLoginText = loginTextField.text {

    let start = actualLoginText
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .short         
    formattedTime = formatter.date(from: start)!
}
```

And this is the code of my logout picker

```
@objc func timeOutPickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    timeOutPicker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: formattedTime)
    logoutTextField.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```

I also tried this but still doesn't work

```
if let actualLoginText = loginTextField.text {

    let start = actualLoginText
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    formattedTime = formatter.date(from: start)!
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: login time when converted returns: 1999-12-31 23:00:00 +0000 while logout is 2018-01-04 22:24:20 +0000. How do I convert the login time to the correct format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login and logout time strings were pulled up from database. And when I don't edit the login textfield it's data remains as string since there was no value change, so I'm forced to use a string value as reference to my logout picker.

the result login being: 1999-12-31 23:00:00 +0000
and logout: 2018-01-04 22:24:20 +0000

this is the reason why using the login as my minimum time didn't work

so here's what I did, I added the current date so I can use it.

```
 @objc func timeOutPickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    if let actualLoginText = loginTextField.text {

        let date = Date()

        let start = actualLoginText
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        let nowTime = formatter.string(from: date)

        let concat = nowTime + " " + start

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"

        formattedTime = dateFormatter.date(from: concat)!

    }

    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.dateStyle = .none

    formatter.timeStyle = .short

    timeOutPicker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: formattedTime)

    logoutTextField.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)


}
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with dates / times, work with `Date` objects, not strings. The "string representation" should only be used to display the date/time to the user, not when manipulating the values.

Here is a simple example (assuming you have added two `UIDatePickers` and connected their `Value Changed` events). On load, it initializes the `timeInPicker` to the current date/time. Any time you select a new "Time In", the `timeOutPicker.minimumDate` is set to 5-minutes from the selected time, and the `timeOutPicker.maximumDate` is set to 8-hours from the minimum time:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeInPicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeOutPicker: UIDatePicker!

    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateStyle = .short
        df.timeStyle = .short
        return df
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Initialize the TimeIn and TimeOut pickers to the current Date/Time
        let now = Date()
        updateTimeOutPicker(now)

    }

    func updateTimeOutPicker(_ withStartDateTime: Date) -> Void {

        // add 5 minutes to the selected "In" time to get the "minimum time" for the Out Picker
        guard let minDateTime = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: withStartDateTime) else { return }

        // add 8 hours to the to get the "maximum time" for the Out Picker
        guard let maxDateTime = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(byAdding: .hour, value: 8, to: minDateTime) else { return }

        timeOutPicker.minimumDate = minDateTime
        timeOutPicker.maximumDate = maxDateTime

        print("New Min Out Time:", dateFormatter.string(from: minDateTime))
        print("New Max Out Time:", dateFormatter.string(from: maxDateTime))
        print()

    }

    @IBAction func timeInPickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

        print("Selected In Time:", dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date))
        print()

        updateTimeOutPicker(sender.date)

    }

    @IBAction func timeOutPickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

        print("Selected Out Time:", dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date))
        print()

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.